# Finding out the range and statistical distribution

Tags: linear-algebra

The range of the heights of the female students in a certain class is 13.2
inches, and the range of the heights of the male students in the class is 15.4
inches.

> **Which of the following statements individually provide(s) sufficient additional information to determine the range of the heights of all
>   the students in the class?**
>
> 1. The tallest male student in the class is 5.8 inches taller than the tallest female student in the class.
> 2. The median height of the male students in the class is 1.1 inches greater than the median height of the female students in the class.
> 3. The average (arithmetic mean) height of the male students in the class is 4.6 inches greater than the average height of the female
>      students in the class.

To solve this prove, I tried to compare the  male and female height range but it seems to me a lengthy process. Have any easy way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

1. Setting tallest male in class as M1 and shortest male as M2, tallest girl as W1 and shortest as W2, then you have a 2x2 matrix, now since in 1) it is given that the tallest male is taller than female (thus tallest person in class is male) so all you need is if the shortest person is male of female but the range is given for both male and females here which if M1-W1=5.8 so you have a third row and clearly the shortest person is a female(if you set the equation M1-M2-(W1-W2)=2.2, knowing M1-W1=5.8, you get 5.8-M2+W2=2.2 and W2=M2-3.6) and plug in the variables and leave M1 and W2 and solve for M1-W2 then u get your answer

Which I did the matrix way and found it to be 19.